# Write down the SQL to show the department in which the average salary of the employees (whose salary is greater than 5000) is less than 8000

Tags: sql

Write down the SQL to show the department in which the average salary of the employees (whose salary is greater than 5000) is less than 8000.

This is what I wrote. I am not sure if this is correct.

```
select departments.department_name, employees.avg(salary) as avgsalary from departments
inner join employees
on departments.department_id = employees.department_id
where avgsalary > 5000 and avgsalary < 8000;
```

Comment: you need a `group by` and a (`having` instead of the `where`)

Comment: and as a suggestion, go to a new line before each `from`, `join`, `where`, `group by`, `having` but not before the `on` (or indent the `on`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select departments.department_name
    , avg(employees.salary) as avgsalary 
from departments inner join employees
    on departments.department_id = employees.department_id
group by departments.department_name
having avg(employees.salary) > 5000 and avg(employees.salary) < 8000;
```